# How do I remove the special highlighting on `rnu` numbers?

Tags: colorscheme

I spent a lot of time getting vim to look just the way I want, but `nornu` and `rnu` number modes look different.  Is there any way to disable the special highlighting when in `rnu` mode?

nornu

[image: nornu]

rnu

[image]

Comment: Why a plugin? Your answer is in `:help highlight-groups`.

Answer (score 4):

You can't change that it is left-aligned, but you can change the highlighting used by modifying the `CursorLineNr` highlighting group, e.g. to make it the same as the other numbering, you could use this:

```
hi! link CursorLineNr LineNr
```